# Scifi show from early 80s: beach with huge worms or cocoons

Tags: story-identification, tv

All I remember is watching it in B&W. It involved 2 kids and an older gentleman that could have been the granddad. They were on a beach where there were HUGE worms or cocoons. They spoke with an accent and the beach was along cliffs (like the Irish shore line). The man was able to teleport. The show may have been in color, and our TV was still a B&W TV, but that is how I remember.

Comment: Was it [Under the mountain](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0202769/?ref_=tt_urv)? The accent would be from New Zealand, not Ireland, but cocoons, two kids and older guy  would match. I'm not sure about teleportation

Comment: @Yasskier - According to [the Wikipedia page for the 2009 movie version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Mountain_(miniseries)), a character named Mr. Jones (an alien who looks like an elderly human) has the power to teleport, amongst other things. There's a character with the same name [in the TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Mountain_(miniseries)), so I think you should definitely submit your guess as an answer ASAP.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Indeed. Before someone incredibly handsome and clever comes along and steals your ideas....

Comment: Unfortunately no Under the Mountain was not it. I had thought as well a little while back so I watched the entire thing & sure enough was not it. They are inside a mountain/ underneath it these cocoons/worms was laying on the beach.

Comment: @Ninjabb did you check the tv series or the movie version of Under the Mountain?

Comment: @NiceOrc I will have to check. I think it was the series it was on you tube. If so I may have to check the movie out if it is slightly different than the series.

Comment: It might help to say what country you're from - without that it's hard to know what you would consider "an accent".

Comment: @Nathaniel I am in the United States

Answer (score 14):

**[Under the Mountain](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0202769/?ref_=tt_urv)** (1981)

The show is from New Zealand, not Ireland, but I guess the OP could not recognize the accent (other than it was from other country).

> Teenage twin siblings, Rachel and Theo, on a summer vacation in Auckland visiting their aunt and uncle, meet a certain Mr. Jones, a mysterious man who helped find them when they got lost in the woods eight years earlier. Mr. Jones turns out to be an alien fighter from a distant planet who wants their help in fighting an alien giant slug family of eight members led by a certain Mr. Wilberforce who have arrived on Earth with plans for world domination.

The "slug people" grow in cocoons and indeed, Mr Jones is able to teleport.

Episode 1 can be found on Youtube (kudos to @Valorum)

Comment: You might want to add a link to youtube; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJpUA3hQyO8